# Trigger To update Field every 24 hours

Tags: mysql, triggers

In my table I have a field called days, I want a trigger to be executed every 24 hours and subtract that field in 1 if it has a 30 and subtract 29 and so on, but I do not know how to do it, I know it is with a **while** I do not know how to do it in **mysql**

```
 While days> = 0 Do
```

> I do not know how to add the following code to the trigger with an
>   update for the days field

```
 floor (((date + (86400 * 30)) - unix_timestamp ()) / 86400) as expire_days
```

Comment: Triggers are triggered when some action happens. That is not the case here.

Comment: You can write a script that is run by your OS like windows task scheduler in any given intervals

Answer (score 0):

Why use a trigger?  Just put in the target date and use a view to calculate the dates:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           greatest(datediff(target_date, curdate()), 0) as days
    from t;
```

The value of `days` will be calculated when the view is called.  No need for scheduling events or jobs.